# How do I get RegEx to get the entire URL... start at http and get everything after until a whitespace and how to exclude certain characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, twitter, match

OK, I have an asp file pulling an rss feed from twitter onto my server, Im using AJAX to break up each entry and write the HTML. I want to be able to extract a link from the description part of the entry but I am having trouble writing the RegEx correctly.

```
$(entry).find('item').each(function() {
    // gets the "id", "title", and "url" of current child element
    $elm = $(this);
    $title = $elm.find('title').text();
    $desc = $elm.find('description').text();
    $pubDate = $elm.find('pubDate').text();
    $guid = $elm.find('guid').text();
    $link = $elm.find('link').text();
    $div.append('<div class="section" id="entry'+$count+'"><h3 class="pubDate">'+$pubDate.slice(0, -6)+'</h3><h3 class="desc">'+$desc+'</h3><div class="linkBox"><a href="'+$link+'" title="'+$title+'" class="link">'+$link+'</a></div></div>');

    $href = $desc.match(/\b(http|https)?(:\/\/)?(\S*)\.(\w{2,4})\b/ig);

    alert($href);
    $count++
});
```

This is what I have so far:

This is the example tweet (raw string):

```
I'm at Harrah's Hotel and Casino: Luxury Suite (New Orleans, LA) w/ 2 others http://t.co/UjxTIdiJ
```

I want to extract the link using this:

```
$desc.match(/\b(http|https)?(:\/\/)?(\S*)\.(\w{2,4})\b/ig);
```

but it only returns:

```
http://t.co
```

I am pulling my hair out trying to get all the characters past http until a whitespace character while excluding commas etc...

Comment: Aren't you missing in the regexp the last bit of the URL after the slash?, e.g (not tested):$desc.match(/\b(http|https)?(:\/\/)?(\S*)\.(\w{2,4})(\/[\S\/]+)?\b/ig);

Comment: does the tweet string have anchor tags?   Can you use a code block to write your tweet string? Can a tweet url have spaces?

Comment: There is no Anchor tag in the xml that is pulled from the rss feed so literally the string reads I'm at Harrah's Hotel and Casino: Luxury Suite (New Orleans, LA) w/ 2 others t.co/UjxTldiJ - stack puts the anchors around but there are none I assure you

Comment: ok thx.  BTW, if you put that in a code block it will be more obvious

Comment: yeah I always forget that thanks

Comment: I added my own answer but can't check it correct for two days per stack rules, thanks for the input though you have been a great help and I upped your answer

Answer (score 1):

This regex should do the trick: `\s*(?i)href\s*=\s*(\"([^"]*\")|'[^']*'|([^'">\s]+))`.

Example: http://regex101.com/r/eL3wV4

Or if you don't have an inline a href: `(http:[^\s]*)|(https[^\s]*)` should just get you `http://*` or `https://*`.

Example: http://regex101.com/r/uE5bZ5

Comment: There is no Anchor tag in the xml that is pulled from the rss feed so literally the string reads I'm at Harrah's Hotel and Casino: Luxury Suite (New Orleans, LA) w/ 2 others http://t.co/UjxTldiJ - stack puts the anchors around but there are none I assure you

Comment: Thanks for showing me this, I am shocked at the lack of searchability for this site here is how I got it to work http://regex101.com/r/eY9cF3

Comment: Didn't consider that stack made a link out of your example. I've made a shorter regex for you. (Bit easier then the one you are currently using. Basically it matches http and https and then any character untill it runs into a whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

OK so here is the solved answer to this question but https://stackoverflow.com/users/1472389/damien-overeem @Damian Overeem should get all the credit for show me regex101 but here is how I got it to select what I wanted:

```
$href = $desc.match(/\b(http|https)?(:\/\/)?(\S*)\.(\w{2,4}(\S*))\b/ig);
```

Check it out here http://regex101.com/r/gT6hC2